# WinForms - change name of form file name

Tags: winforms

I have a project that I've been working on, and I need to import an existing form that someone else has created. The file name of the form I need to import is Form2.vb. However, there is already a Form2.vb in my current project. How do I add the other Form2.vb file in VS without replacing the Form2.vb that's already in my project?

Comment: There's no way to "Add Existing Item" in this case?

Comment: It's like with anything, it thinks you want to duplicate the original, you have to use different names I'm afraid

Comment: Ya I know I need to use different names, I'm asking if there is a way to change the name of the form file? Form2 is actually FrmMain inside my vb project, but in the directory the file name is still Form2.vb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't leave your files with the default name like `FormN.vb`.  Rename the existing file to match its function.  Once you do that, you could import the other form without a naming conflict.  Once you import it, give it a good name that matches its function.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a little new to .net. I did change my Form2 to FrmMain, but the file in my vb folder still says Form2.vb. Do I need to change the file name in the directory?

Comment: Click on the file in the solution explorer, twice slowly, and it should allow you to change the file name.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I didn't know about this functionality (obviously)